# How to include a custom AlertDialog in OnClickListener of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to put a custom alertDialog when I press an imageView, but the application breaks.

I tried to pass an activity and onClicklistener, but it does not work

My custom AlertDialog is this:

```
public vlass viewInfoAjustes{
   public void showDialog(Activity activity){
      final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
      dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      dialog.setCancelable(false);
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.icono_info_ajustes);
      Button ok = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

      ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
         }
      });

      dialog.show();
   }
}
```

and I call it this way:

```
    ImageView info = findViewById(R.id.boton_infoServer);
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {              
            ViewInfoAjustes iconoInfo = new ViewInfoAjustes();
            iconoInfo.showDialog(this);
        }
    });
```

this is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Fragment then use

`iconoInfo.showDialog(getContext());`

if you are using Activity then use :

```
iconoInfo.showDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MyActivity.this` for that case

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing **v.getContext()** in your **showDialog()** method.